# How to send Array/list/JSON between 2 components Angular 2 by routing?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have no idea how to make it good.
I want to send JSON between 2 Angular Components. I thinking about routing but how to send something like POST between this, to components i know how to use @inputs/@Outputs , but i have to change Url and reload content. The problem is it is not only id  but  list of check ides.

Component

```
  selectedAll = [];// it is array od Id [1,2,3,4...];
  goToDetail(): void {
    this.selectedIDService.saveIds(this.selectedLight);
    console.log( "Show: "+this.selectedIDService.retrieveIDs().length); <-- give me good number

    this.router.navigate(['/detailSearch']);
  }
```

HTML button nothong intresting

> ```
> <button  class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"  (click)="gotoDetail()">
> ```

Of course i want to get this on my detailSearch component.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SelectedIdService {

  public myIds: Array<Number>=[];
  constructor() { }

  saveIds(produIds:any){
    this.myIds = produIds;
    console.log(this.myIds);
  }
  retrieveIDs():any[]{
    return this.myIds;
  } 
}
```

--------Other component-------

```
 providers : [SelectedIdService]
constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute,
               private  selectedIdService :SelectedIdService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
     var selected:any[] =this.selectedIdService.retrieveIDs();<<-- empty
}
```

do u know why?

Answer (score 2):

Use a **`service`** to save the array of ids from one component to other component. It's not a safe way to pass it over the url.

Create a service like this,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class AppMessageQueuService {

    myIds: Array<Number>=[];
    constructor() {

    }
    saveIds(produIds:any){
        this.myIds = produIds;
    }
    retrieveIDs(){
        return this.myIds;
    }

}
```

Then you can inject this Service into both the components and save it from the first component like,

```
this.appMsgService.saveIds(yourIds);
```

then retrieve in the second component as,

```
this.appMsgService.retrieveIDs(yourIds);
```

you can inject to your component as,

```
constructor(
   private appMsgService: AppMessageQueuService
)
```

Comment: maybe it is not safe, but it is working business want to change link so i have to make it like this.

Comment: in the Other components i have empty array :(

Comment: That is not an issue :)

Comment: selected-id.service.ts:11 (4) [1, 2, 3, 4]
search-standard.component.ts:87 show: 4
detail-result.component.ts:29 show 0

Answer (score 1):

Send JSON between 2 Angular Components, you need to use a provider service. [official docs](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)